# Rangy - Apply Style to Parent Blocks

Tags: javascript, rangy

I use Rangy.js to apply styles to inline elements like this:

```
rangy.createClassApplier(className, { elementTagName: tagName });
Applier.toggleSelection();
```

How would I go about applying a class to the parents of any selected items?  For instance, I want to add a class to any paragraph that is a parent of a selection -

Comment: @TimDown have you seen this one?